# Random shuffling an array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, random, shuffle

I need to randomly shuffle an array of 10 names:

`String[] names={"name 1", "name 2", "name 3", "name 4", "name 5", "name 6", "name 7", "name 8", "name 9", "name 10"};`

What function could i use to solve this?

Comment: Please take the time to search for your answer on both this site and the net in general before posting a question. Duplicates only serve to make finding the correct answer more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Arrays.asList` to create a `List` backed by the original array, then call `Collections.shuffle`.

```java
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(names));
```